# make multiple button click values hold in text box

Tags: javascript, html

In text box because of button click event text is transfer to text box, this text hold its place after also another click event which pass new value to text box.  The text box hold the value for multiple click event.

Comment: i was tried to add text box innerHTML and buttons innerHTML   but it didn't .

Answer (score 0):

in each click function,you should get the text box's value,and then add the new value to it .Then put the "sum" to the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what you mean, but I made two codes that are quite simple and should get you to understand how this works approx.

You can achieve what you mean with createTextNode and appendChild.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/47pfcbeL/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>text</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function trantxt(input) {
var obj=document.getElementById(input);
var txt=document.getElementById('text1').value;
var txtarea=document.createTextNode(txt);
obj.appendChild(txtarea);
}

function addtxt(input) {
var obj=document.getElementById(input);
var txt=document.createTextNode("blah blah");
obj.appendChild(txt);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Case 1: Transfer text from textbox to textarea.</h1>
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Write here" />

<input type="button" value="Transfer" onclick="trantxt('textarea1')">
<textarea id="textarea1" placeholder="Content comes here"></textarea>

<h1>
    Or... if you mean this
</h1>


<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
<br><input type="button" value="Write blah blah" onclick="addtxt('textarea2')">
</body>
</html>
```